# Why is my MySQL query slow?

Tags: mysql

This query is taking over a minute about 500,000 records

name is a CHAR

userid is a unique primary INT

locked_date is an INT representing unix_timestamp

The rest are either 0 or 1 TINYINT

Any tips on how to make this query faster?

```
SELECT  name,userid 
FROM  `sn` 
FORCE INDEX(unlock_target2)
WHERE `locked`  = 1 
and `unlocked` = 0 
and (back_locked = 0 or back_unlocked = 1) 
and flag = 0 
and deleted = 0     
ORDER BY locked_date ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Explained select

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sn    | ref  | unlock_target2   | unlock_target2   | 2       | const,const | 6716 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Create

```
CREATE TABLE `sn` (
`date_added` int(11) NOT NULL,
`userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`name` char(30) NOT NULL,
`status` char(15) NOT NULL,
`pool` char(30) NOT NULL,
`flag` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`turn` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`private` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`media_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
`props_received` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
`locker_count` int(10) DEFAULT '-1',
`locking_count` int(10) DEFAULT '-1',
`commenter` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`props` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`locked_date` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`locked` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`unlocked` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`back_locked` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`back_unlocked` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`media_propped` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date_propped` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
UNIQUE KEY `userid_2` (`userid`),
KEY `userid` (`userid`),
KEY `unlock_target1` (`back_unlocked`,`locked`,`unlocked`,`flag`,`deleted`,`locked_date`),
KEY `unlock_target2` (`locked`,`unlocked`,`back_unlocked`,`flag`,`deleted`,`locked_date`),
KEY `index_locked` (`locked`),
KEY `index_unlocked` (`unlocked`),
KEY `index_back_locked` (`back_locked`),
KEY `index_flag` (`flag`),
KEY `index_deleted` (`deleted`),
KEY `index_locked_date` (`locked_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement of your table and the create statements for your indices. Also, include the output of a `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` statement to see what MySQL is doing with your query.

Comment: Also note, the locked_unlocked index didn't really help as the problem seems to be back_unlocked DESC as tested

Comment: You might want to add an index on the columns used in the `WHERE` clause, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148943/mysql-performance-slow-using-filesort

Comment: I tried adding an index for all field in WHERE, also an index for all fields in WHERE + ORDER BY. The query is still taking over 60 seconds to complete. A clue is that when ORDER BY is stripped, the query is instant. I have removed userid from the sort, but locked_date is essential (it's a unix timestamp)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the statement which creates the index for the columns in your `WHERE` condition and include the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` statement after you have added the index.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: What happens if you put `locked_date` as the first field in the `unlock_target2` key?