# Even with indexes, mysql inner join is 50-500x slower than 2 separate queries

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm getting very unexpected poor performance from an inner join and I'm at a loss to explain it because all the necessary indexes appear to be in place and it runs at least 50x faster if I split it into 2 queries. Yet to me, it's the exact type of query that a relational database is supposed to be good at. MySQL 5.6 if it matters. The account table has ~4K records, the event table ~500M.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_account` (
  `accountID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accountKey` varchar(767) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  ...,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountID`),
  KEY `index_accountKey` (`accountKey`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_event` (
  `eventID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fkAccount` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `creationDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  ...,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventID`),
  KEY `index_fkAccount` (`fkAccount`),
  KEY `index_creationDate` (`creationDate`),
  KEY `index_fkAccount_creationDate` (`fkAccount`, `creationDate`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_fkAccount` FOREIGN KEY (`fkAccount`) REFERENCES `tbl_account` (`accountID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I run the following query, it takes a minimum of 5.5s, sometimes almost a minute.

```
SELECT e.* FROM tbl_event e INNER JOIN tbl_account a ON e.fkAccount = a.accountID
WHERE a.accountKey = 'abcdefghij'
  AND e.creationDate >= '2019-02-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY e.creationDate DESC
LIMIT 500;
```

If I look up the accountID(s) independently first, it consistently takes only 0.03s for the first query, and 0.1s for the 2nd (when I tell it to use the compound index, mysql sometimes wants to just use index_creationDate on its own).

```
SELECT a.accountID FROM tbl_account a WHERE a.accountKey = 'abcdefghij';
/*returns accountID = 123*/

SELECT e.* FROM tbl_event e USE INDEX (index_fkAccount_creationDate)
WHERE e.fkAccount IN (123)
  AND e.creationDate >= '2019-02-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY e.creationDate DESC
LIMIT 500;
```

Some notes:

- It's not because of caching. I've run it in different orders, with different day and account filters and the results are consistent when I know it's not cached.
- If it matters, accountID to accountKey is mostly 1-1, but not quite, there are a some accountKeys that have multiple accountID values. That's why the last where clause uses an IN.
- I know index_accountKey in tbl_account does not need to be full length of varchar field to save the index size, but that's not the issue for this problem.
- In tbl_event, index_fkAccount is redundant now that a compound index exists with it as the first field, but it's currently still in my real table, so I put it here too.

Output from EXPLAIN on the select using join:

```
table       | type | key                          | ref                   |rows| Extra
tbl_account | ref  | index_accountKey             | const                 |001 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
tbl_event   | ref  | index_fkAccount_creationDate | tbl_account.accountID |116 | Using index condition
```

Why does EXPLAIN say it will be "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" to return 1 row from tbl_account? When I look up the tbl_account row on its own, it's just "Using where". I'm not returning any rows from tbl_account as part of the order by, so what's it trying to sort? Shouldn't it just look up the accountID in tbl_account and then plug it into tbl_event and use the index there?

I've tried putting the filter into the ON clause. I've tried using a subquery but nothing improves it. Is this just poor optimization by MySQL, and I need to split the queries, or is there something I can do to make it run quickly with the join?

Comment: `...that have multiple accountID values` - I'm not saying it's wrong, but I didn't quite understand the logic of that statement

Comment: It was just my poorly-worded way of saying that accountKey is not a unique value/index in tbl_account. (95% of the values are unique, but there are a few duplicates in there).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your query:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM tbl_event e 
INNER JOIN tbl_account a ON e.fkAccount = a.accountID
WHERE a.accountKey = 'abcdefghij'
AND e.creationDate >= '2019-02-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY e.creationDate DESC
LIMIT 500;
```

must do a table scan (qualified by creation_date) of the tbl_event table, and then for each row, find the matching tbl_account row and compare the given value with the tbl_account.accountKey value.

You may have better luck reversing the order of the tables in the query as follows:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM tbl_account a 
INNER JOIN tbl_event e ON e.fkAccount =a.accountID
WHERE a.accountKey='k3'
ORDER BY e.creationDate DESC
LIMIT 500;
```

This should first select tbl_account rows that match the given key, then find the tbl_event rows that correspond to those, and were created on or after the given timestamp.

Here's a [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b9767/2) I created to test this .

Comment: So this was faster?

Comment: No that has the same execution plan and slow result as the original query. It doesn't even help if I move the a.accountKey filter out of the WHERE and into the ON.

Comment: Perhaps the answer lies in this Stackoverflow question [MYSQL performance slow using filesort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148943/mysql-performance-slow-using-filesort)